# How to change a url for the first element only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

I want to be able to change a url directory for, e.g. the first `<img>` in a `<div>`, or, any image that is not the first.

My reason is that the loading speed is too slow. That's because I used CSS to generate thumbnails from larger images. I now want to redirect those thumbnail images to a thumbnail folder with small images, rather than having to redirect them individually, which would be a pain.

```
<img src="images/stories/Images_for_Web/baths_windowToTheSoul_WB4_p90.jpg">
<img src="images/stories/Thumbs/baths_windowToTheSoul_WB4_p90.jpg">
```

here is the link to the site I'm working on: http://www.d1187169-1.cp.blacknight.com/whitebook1/

I have the CSS automatically resizing and cropping the images for any that is not the first. I like that solution as it will save work in the future so if this part could work also, it would be brilliant, unfortunately I just know CSS, HTML, a little Joomla and only starting in javascript etc., but I am willing to try anything to get this to work!

Any thoughts or suggestions much appreciated. Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use jQuery, you could do the following:

```
$("#somediv img:first").attr("src", "images/new/location");
```

As you can see just one line of code thanks to the CSS-like selectors. I highly recommend using jQuery for such tasks.

Comment: brilliant, that looks like what I'm looking for! Thanks for the coding tip!

Comment: OK, I've installed jQuery and set up a test example: http://paulodonovan.net/jQuery_test.html However I am having trouble getting it to work. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong? I've created the new thumbnail folder and for the test, when the jQuery works (replaces the directory), both images will look the same (I hope).

Comment: Paul, I think your script is actually working, although what I've noticed is that http://paulodonovan.net/images/thumbs/4.jpg and http://paulodonovan.net/images/5.jpg are the same files, so maybe that's confusing you?

Comment: Yeah that's confusing sorry, but yes I got the script to replace an image successfully :) ..now I just need to find out how to replace the first part of an image `src` directory so that I don't need to redirect each image individually. Is it possible to do this for just part of the `src`, so it would work on any image, where there are two folders with the same images, one folder (thumbs) would just have a batch of small images? Maybe selecting the first 20 or so characters or is there an easier way, e.g. just replace the folder name itself?

Comment: I take you mean you want to edit a part of the src string? Have a look at using [substrings](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) or [Regex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Comment: Thanks - they're cool but I think I see another problem in this approach: if I have to use the `$(document).ready(function() {` command, scripts won't take effect until after the large images are loaded, not decreasing the load time at all. Or am I wrong? Please say I'm wrong! hehe

Comment: Well you don't necessarily have to use `$(document).ready` but if you want to make sure that you avoid loading the big images you have to use a server-side solution, not a client-side (JavaScript) solution.

Comment: I'll try rename my images folder to e.g. 'Images_2', then create a new empty directory using the original name. Then depend entirely on jQuery to redirect images - the theory being that the excessively large thumbnail images will never be loaded.

Comment: If that doesn't work I'll venture into the server side, hopefully I can still use my CSS selectors?.

Comment: A server side solution is something like PHP etc.. You are basically using a programming language to generate an HTML page on the server and serve it to the user. This is independent from your CSS. Unless you mean whether you can use CSS selectors on the server - the answer would be no, as you are generating the HTML yourself. I hope I understand what you're trying to say. If you're happy with all my help please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi MMM, I learnt a lot from all that, thanks! I think php is already in use on the main joomla site I first mentioned - I wonder can php select the first element like in CSS. I'm still trying to avail of the substrings or Regex - I'm new to all this so I'll look for an example of how that might work, then try implement it with the Joomla site, so it's compatible with mootools. I've tried plugins to make jQuery run with Joomla but no joy. I won't quit just yet! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnails should be generated with php/on the server side. Resizing with CSS is not really resizing - still the full image is loaded.

Maybe you should look in jQuery - it has selectors that are like CSS selectors.

Comment: Definitely look at jQuery first.  I wouldn't casually introduce an application framework like php